# Platform.runLater() method

Tags: multithreading, javafx, platform

I'm trying to understand, whether Platform.runLater() method invokes just the SAME JavaFxApplicationThread, as in start()-method or ANOTHER, PARALLEL thread with the same name?

In the code below:

1) first, start()-method was invoked with JavaFxApplicationThread;

2) then, startFilling()-method was invoked, where new thread starts;

3) at last, new Stage was opened with method openMessage(), where Platform.runLater() method was used.

Please see the code:

```
public class FillingTimeLine extends Application {
private LongProperty lp = new SimpleLongProperty(0);
private Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("\nSTARTING THREAD: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    StackPane spane = new StackPane();
    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0);
    pb.setMinSize(160, 21.5);
    pb.setMaxSize(160, 21.5);
    pb.setPrefSize(160, 21.5);

    pb.progressProperty().bind(lp.divide(10000 * 1.0));
    pb.setStyle("-fx-base:darkgray;-fx-accent:red;");
    spane.getChildren().add(pb);
    Scene scene = new Scene(spane, 300, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    startFilling();
    openNewStage();

}

public void startFilling() throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("\nSTARTING THREAD: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new KeyValue(lp, 0)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(20), new KeyValue(lp, 20000)));
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("\n THR WAS INTERRUPTED!");
            return;
        }

        timeline.play();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("\n THR WAS INTERRUPTED!");
            return;
        }

    }).start();

}

public void stopFilling() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("\nSTOPPING THREAD: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        timeline.stop();

    }).start();
}

public void openNewStage() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {

        System.out.println("\nOPENNING THREAD" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Stage qst = new Stage();
        StackPane sp = new StackPane();
        Button btn = new Button("STOP");

        btn.setMaxHeight(25);
        btn.setMinHeight(25);
        btn.setPrefHeight(25);
        btn.setMaxWidth(80);
        btn.setMinWidth(80);
        btn.setPrefWidth(80);

        btn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                qst.close();
                stopFilling();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                return;
            }
        });

        sp.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 200, 120);
        qst.setX(50);
        qst.setY(50);
        qst.setScene(scene);
        qst.setResizable(false);
        qst.show();
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

I thougt Platform.runLater() enables parallel execution. And I expected, that new Stage with a STOP-button would be opened by another thread, because JavaFxApplicationThread was still busy with primaryStage.

But CONSOLE PUTPUT shows that new Stage was opened also with JavaFxApplicationThread- just as primaryStage:

STARTING THREAD: JavaFX Application Thread

STARTING THREAD: Thread-3

OPENNING THREAD: JavaFX Application Thread

STOPPING THREAD: Thread-4

So how can one and the same thread open new Stage, if primaryStage is still showing and is not closed?

Or is OPENING THREAD - another, parallel thread with the same name?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where did you read `Platform.runLater() enables parallel execution` at?

Comment: Why would you use a thread to stop and start a Timeline?

Comment: Threads should be used to handle long running task that do alter the GUI. Starting or stoping a Timeline is not a long running task.

Comment: Think about you writing on a pad of paper, you can write on the top sheet, then flip to the next page and write something else; you're still the UI Thread working with two sheets (stages).  Now you're happily writing on the sheets of paper and you need me to spell something for you - so I go and look it up and write the answer down on a post it note (runLater) so that when you're done what you're doing now, you can use my post it note to update your page with the correct spelling.

Comment: Sedrick, thank you for your comment.  I've just supposed that Platform.runLater() enables parallel execution. Yes, I see: threads are redundant

Comment: Kendavidson, thank you. It seems, that JavaFxApplicationThread differs from usual threads and has more sophisticated structure. Does it?

Comment: No, `Platform.runLater()` does not allow/enable/perform parallel processing. In fact, it does not even execute the code, but simply puts it in the queue of the `javafx application thread` "message processing cycle". Thus, at some point in the future, `javafx application thread` will reach the specific message (after processing everything before it, understandably) and execute it.

Comment: The _JavaFX Application Thread_ is special because of its relationship with the user interface—but it's still just a `Thread` like any other.

Comment: Should have been "do not alter the GUI" above.